# Alternate for RowCommand event for Checkbox inside Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview inside controls such as checkbox and textbox. For Checkbox,there is no CommandName property like button available for using it in RowCommand Event of Gridview. Whenever,checkbox checked state is changed,I need to enable some button outside the gridview. Is there any alternate way to achieve this?

Below is the code snippet which I have tried but button is not getting enabled,

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkFee" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkFee_Changed" />   

           protected void chkFee_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                BtnCalculate.Enabled = true;
                btnSubmit.Enabled = false;                
            } 
In Javascript is called before the this Checkedchanged event,
 function Calc(obj) {

            var BtnCalculate = document.getElementById("<%= BtnCalculate.ClientID %>");
               BtnCalculate.disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Aspx File..............

```
   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBook" runat="server" 
    AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkBook_Changed" />
```

This is cs file..........

```
protected void chkAssignAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow) ((DataControlFieldCell) ((CheckBox) sender).Parent).Parent;
                CheckBox chk1 = (CheckBox) gr.FindControl("chkAssignSun");
                CheckBox chk2 = (CheckBox) gr.FindControl("chkAssignMon");

                chk1.Checked = ((CheckBox) sender).Checked;
                chk2.Checked = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;                    
            }
```

Try this code.............

Comment: I have diabled the button from Javascript and I just wanted to enable it in checkedchanged event,I have done the same,but the button is still disable.